# How to implement ::ms-clear in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In Internet Explorer-10;

When i "text-align" right to any input type textbox.

The visibility of last digit gets bad.

[image]

This is bug in IE-10 rendering following solution is given

```
::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

As i am not familiar much with CSS; i do not know how to implement "two colon class" on particular input type.

Could any one help me out?

1) How to mention ::-ms-clear in INLINE STYLES?

2) How to make class of above one and implement on particular code?

Following is HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" value="" data-require-number="true" id="belop">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this for `input type text` as a class, and you can't use this in inline style.

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear{
  display: none;
}
```

**Update :-**

css -

```
 .className::-ms-clear{
  display: none;
}
```

html -

```
<input type="text" value="" data-require-number="true" id="belop" class="className">
```

Comment: But i do not want it to implement on all texts

Comment: Then simply add with class, see the update may it will helps you.

Comment: Trying it. Thanks for quick response :)

Comment: You could target it with the id instead, as it already exists.

Comment: @ralph.m How can you use `id` it will use only once and `class` use multiple time.

Comment: Sure, if you need it more than once on the page, then the ID is no use … unless each element you want to style has an ID already, in which case you can write a rule for each one, which is a bit inefficient though.