# How to use :-ms-reveal as inline style in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to hide the eye(*Password Reveal control*) which appear while entering password in inputbox in Microsoft Edge. For hiding it, we need to use `:-ms-reveal`. I tried to use it like **`MsReveal`** in inline style of react, but didn't work. Due to CSS file restrictions, I need to use inline styles in my project. So could anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922878/set-text-input-placeholder-color-in-reactjs

Comment: please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835837/how-to-implement-ms-clear-in-css You can't write this as inline css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took almost a day to find the solution which I was looking for. Scenario was if you don't want to use 3rd party packages like [Radium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium) or [Emotion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/css) (*css-to-js*), you can follow below method.

Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for adding your code.

```
    const inputFieldStyle = `
               .inputField::-ms-reveal{
                       display: 'none'
               }`
```

Then you can use `<style>` tag where you pass above style like below:

```
const reactFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  ...
  return(
    <>
      <style>
        {inputFieldStyle}
      </style>
    ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.